# Splitting a string into an array

Tags: objective-c, ios7

Pretty new to objective-C trying to understand how I can split a string I have. I actually think I split the string already, now I just want to test it out so I am trying to set it to a textview, getting an "incompatable pointer type" warning. I did read some things online, however they don't match with what I saw in class, and my professor told us iOS changes all the time, and that some solutions I might find might not work anymore. This is why I am coming to SO, I did try to find this information out on my own, however all SO links were 2+ years old so I wanted to be safe and re-ask this question for anyone using iOS 7 +.

```
- (IBAction)GetCourse:(id)sender
{
    __block NSString * jstring = nil;
    __block NSArray * jarray = nil;

    dispatch_queue_t progressQueue = dispatch_queue_create("JSON.GetJSONString", NULL);
    dispatch_async(progressQueue, ^{
            jstring = [JSONHelper JSONgetString:@"http://iam.colum.edu/portfolio/api/course?json=True"];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //main thread code
            //textView.text = jstring;
            jarray = [jstring componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
            textView.text = jarray;
            NSError *error = nil;
            NSDictionary *results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [jstring dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                                    options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                      error: &error];
            if (error) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] JSON error: %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), error.localizedDescription);
        });
    });
```

Comment: You're trying to place an NSArray as text in a TextView?  Pretty sure you should have an NSString there.

Comment: yeah, it's what I used when I had the parsed JSON all in one string I am trying to split it now so that's the issue I am having.

Comment: Well compenentsSeparatedByString returns an NSArray.  So yes, you've successfully separated your string by spaces.

Comment: Right.. I was trying to display it though mate. ;)

Comment: Ahh, I see.  I would recommend using the debugger or log statements instead of a `UITextView` in the future.  `NSLog("Array: %@", jarray)` will display your array nicely and will take much less time than setting up the connections to a `UITextView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `textView.text` is a property of type `NSString` and `jarray` is an `NSArray`. Try this instead to put the first course name string in the text view:

```
textView.text = [jarray objectAtIndex:0];
```

Then try something like this to put the whole batch of courses appended together into the text view:

```
NSString * fullString = [NSString string];
for(int i = 0; i < jarray.count; i++)
{
    fullString = [fullString stringByAppendingString:[jarray objectAtIndex:i]];
}
textView.text = fullString;
```

*Update:* After looking at the JSON response you probably do want to split the string you get as there is an easier way to get at the data. You want to serialize an `NSArray` of `NSStrings` from the JSON response. Your code is trying to serialize it to an `NSDictionary` which won't work because the response (as I see it) is an array of strings, not a dictionary of values. Try this at the bottom of your block:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray * resultArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [jstring dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers                                                                      error: &error];

if ( !resultArray ) {
    NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", e);
} else {
   for(NSString * course in resultArray) {
      NSLog(@"Course: %@", course);
   }
}
```

Comment: ok thank you! Pretty much what I needed to know, will play around with this more. (will upvote this when the time limit is up).